# Можно ли в SPA PWA хранить данные от запросов с пагинацией?

Tags: pwa

Задумываюсь над выбором: делать или гибридное приложение или PWA. Задача состоит в том, что бы на клиенте хранить слепок данных из ДБ и точечно их обновлять при изменении на сервере. Поможет ли мне в этом PWA?